# Starting and stopping a particle system in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Please, I like to ask how I can start a particle system in iOS /cocos2d, make it run for a certain amount of time say 10 seconds and then have it stopped.

A little code snippet or example which will serve as a guide would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Assuming ps is your particle system, you can start and stop it like this:

```
[ps resetSystem]; // starts, newly created effects are already running
[ps stopSystem];  // stops
```

Waiting for 10 seconds can be done scheduling a selector with 10 second interval.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps :)

```
-(void)addParticles
{
  [particles resetSystem]; //restarts particles
}

-(void)playParticles //call this later somewhere in your code e.g in touches began [self playParticles];
{
  id playParticles = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(addParticles)];
  id stopParticles = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(stopParticles)];
  id wait = [CCActionInterval actionWithDuration:3];
  CCSequence *Particlesbegin = [CCSequence actions:wait,playParticles,wait,stopParticles, nil];
  [self runAction: Particlesbegin];
}

-(void)stopParticles
 {
  [particles stopSystem];
 }



//in touches began
if(CGRectContainsPoint(Btn.boundingBox, location))
{
    [self playParticles];
}
```